# How to remove numbers from json in python

Tags: python, regex, split

I having some json format like

```
json= 5843080158430803{"name":"NAME", "age":"56",}
```

So, how i get `{"name":"NAME", "age":"56",}` Using regex/split (which one is bets method for it) in Python.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Your json variable syntax is incorrect. Is it a string, then you should have quote at start and end

Comment: This question is for that incorrect json format only. Want to convert like that format in proper json using regex/split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the first occurance of `{` into an array, and get the second element in the array.

We also have to add the `{` again because its removed by the split function

```
json = '5843080158430803{"name":"NAME", "age":"56",}'
json = '{' + json.split('{', 1)[1]
print(json)
```

Result: `{"name":"NAME", "age":"56",}`

Comment: is there any other way to do like using regex

Comment: Well yes, but i would say that it is unessecary to use regex for such a simple task

Comment: So can you please guide how we can do this using regex

Comment: Use the following regex: `({.*)` - It just matches `{` and everything proceeding it

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could split at at the first `{` and then replace the part prior to it.

I am assuming the json you have above is actually a string. Then you could do:

```
json_prefix = json.split("{")
json = json.replace(json_prefix, "")
```